# PHP - looping through an array of JSON Variables

Tags: php, ajax, arrays

I have the following array that is in PHP (this is a print_r() output).

I'm currently struggling to loop through this data - need to be able to process each part and access the values in each array item. How can I do this.

I've tried the following unsuccessfully...

```
foreach (array as $key => $value) {
 echo $key;
}
```

[image]

Comment: you have objects there not arrays, perhaps you should try parsing your json in an associative way with `json_decode($string, true)`

Comment: It is an array, but the members are objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. Since you have an array of objects, you should be able to access each object property using ->

```
foreach($array as $value) {
    echo $value -> userid;
}
```

It should echo out all the user id in that array of objects

Answer (score 4):

You have an array of objects, so try something like this:

```
<?php
foreach ($array as $value) {
    echo $value->userid;
    echo $value->action;
    echo $value->photo_name;
}
```

You don't need the `$key` since you're not using it in the loop. Each iteration will put the object in the `$value` variable, on which you can access it's properties.

Comment: thankyou... your answer is also correct... voted up... cheers